# How can I reset my network adapter?

Tags: wifi

Many times my network adapter just stops working, the only option is to reboot anyway.Is there a way to reset network adapter in a session so I won't have to reboot my computer many times?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you need to reset your wi-fi or ethernet card? Is your wi-fi (card) (I am not sure there is such a thing as wifi card) or all of your networking not working? e.g. if you try to connect with ethernet cable can you be able to connect or all internet connections etc. are not working? I am not only saying this so you can get your answer quicker also in future people with similar problems can find this page easier and find the solution easier hopefully.

Comment: Also consider disabling power saving on your Wi-Fi device. Post another question with the output of `lshw -c network` if you need help with this.

Comment: I would like to reset my WiFi card. I have an external WiFi card(USB one).

Comment: Are you using a Lenovo laptop by any chance?

Comment: @personinsack, did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

There is an answer that may work for you:

> If you really want to reset the network adapter you usually need to
>   unload and reload the kernel module that it uses.
>
> If you just want to reconfigure it you can usually do:
>
> `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`
>
> But if you just want a new
>   dhcp lease (that's the technical name for obtain a new IP from the
>   router), you just need to use:
>
> `sudo dhclient -v eth1`

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/54710/how-do-i-reset-the-network-adapter-using-a-terminal-command

Comment: Sorry not working

Comment: @personinsack can you check this thread : 
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-913407.html last message from a member named "desconocido".

Answer (score 2):

I use this command and it works just fine for me:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I use it to restart wifi whenever it stops working (it was much more of an issue after new release of Ubuntu/Xubuntu 16.04, in Loki it's much more stable for me so I use it very little, usually after many suspends).

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` will also work.

Comment: probably.. I no longer have such issues on any machine, so i can't help to test it..

Comment: It's been a while since I upgraded my personal laptop, so if it was fixed or improved, I don't have that improvement. The command I posted is what I used. Three times today (maybe it's time to upgrade).

Comment: some improvements are expected after 6 years since the answer was posted, but the issue may as well depend on hardware, drivers, and such.. my current slimbook laptop came with elementary OS preinstalled, so probably I should have few such issues to begin with.. I recommend posting a new question with details of your system, if you want some help with it (you can link this page in your question)..

Comment: One wonders what the appropriate commands are for Elementary OS 7 (Horus). Neither `service network-manager restart` (ancient `init.d`method) nor `systemctl restart network-manager` (under modern `systemd`) exist any longer. There _is_ a unit called `NetworkManager`, but restarting it won't produce any significative changes — I believe it only affects the network icon on the top bar.